# Sonata Admin sonata_type_collection how to know if it's new item

Tags: javascript, symfony, sonata-admin

In a sonata admin, using a sonata_type_collection to manage oneToMany relation, when adding new item to the collection (in the front end) is there any way to check (with javascript / jQuery) that the newlly added form is the new one ?

I cannot find anywhere in the DOM elements any information to distinguish new items than existing item.

Anybody has a global solution ? (global because I don't want to add « ID » fields on every collections of my application to guess that it's a new item or not)